# Angular search filter and dates not working

Tags: angularjs, date, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to filter a list generated with ng-repeat that contains date objects from a server in the format of milliseconds. The list generates fine and I format it with angular date, but when I filter I'm assuming that the filter is working on the milliseconds, not the text. Do I need to format the dates in a controller or service before I display them to get the filter to work, or is there a way around this?

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="dates">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="DateController">

    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" ng-model="searchText">
    <p>{{dates}}</p>
    <ul ng-repeat="record in records | filter: searchText">
      <li>{{record.activity}}</li>
      <li>{{record.date | date: longDate}}</li>
    </ul>
   </body>
</html>
```

here is my javascript:

```
angular.module('dates', []);

var DateController = function($scope) {
  $scope.records = [{date:1403802879000, activity: "biking"}, {date:1276495200000, activity: "hiking"}, {date:1403802879000, activity: "walking"}, 
  {date:1403802879000, activity: "biking"}, {date:1276495200000, activity: "hiking"}];
}
```

Here is a plunker: http://plnkr.co/byQkzHSTXLHPCdU0pj3o

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are correct that ng-filter will look at the $scope.records array and return a new array based on the expression you enter (in this case searchText)

Easy solution, just convert dates to strings in your $scope.records.

Hard solution, you can write your own ng-filter module. 
https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/filter/filter.js#L3

Comment: Both of these look like acceptable solutions to me -- and in this case I don't have to worry about performance, but in a situation where I did have a ridiculous amount of records, would one or the other be a better solution?

Comment: if you had a ridiculous amount of records... I would suggest keeping them inside a database like mongodb

Then in the searchText model have it so that every time it is updated make an http.post request to find the objects that match your searchText.

There is a limit to how many records can be kept inside the web browser, and there is an even lower limit to how many records can be displayed in the web browser before performance becomes slow.

If you do keep everything in the web browser, it would be good to paginate the display and keep it to <100

Comment: Unless you are doing some math with the dates in your application. I think it would be better to just change their format to a string and rely on the native filter.js provided by angular.

Or just convert the ms into a date via a function.